# Swift - Parallax Header View - ScrollView overlap cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, parallax

I am trying to custom a extension for Parallax Header. However, it's not working perfectly. The table header view always floats and overlaps cells.

[image]

Extension code:

```
extension UITableView {

  func addImageHeaderView(headerView headerView: UIView, height: CGFloat) {
    self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(height, 0, 0, 0)
    self.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -height)
    self.tableHeaderView = headerView
    self.tableHeaderView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: height)
  }

  func updateHeaderView(height kTableHeaderHeight: CGFloat) {

    var headerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: -kTableHeaderHeight , width: self.bounds.width, height: kTableHeaderHeight)
    if self.contentOffset.y < -kTableHeaderHeight {
      headerRect.origin.y = self.contentOffset.y
      headerRect.size.height = -self.contentOffset.y
    }
    self.tableHeaderView?.frame = headerRect
  }

}
```

Implementing Code :

```
tableView.addImageHeaderView(headerView: viewHeader, height: 100)

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      tableView.updateHeaderView(height: 200)
    }
```

Am I wrong at something? Please show me if you know.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to set the following in **viewDidLoad**

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

in swift

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
```

Also what you can try to do is to check the result of the following

```
tableView.addImageHeaderView(headerView: viewHeader, height: 0)

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
      tableView.updateHeaderView(height: 200)
    }
```

please notice that i changed the height from 100 to **0** 
i did it because the height value will change the contentInset of your table view and this is exactly the distance from the top corner

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'UIEdgeInsets' to type 'UIRectEdge'. Got this error.

Comment: Thanks! I found it but no effect. :|

Comment: can you please try the following:  

self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) 
self is your tableView and when you change its contentSet it will be the distance from top

Comment: func addImageHeaderView(headerView headerView: UIView, height: CGFloat) {
    self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    ...
  }
 Is that right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118347/discussion-between-an-le-and-ran-hassid).

Comment: Now, I have new task to custom a lib (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607639/discussion-swift-popup-tooltip)  look like this https://github.com/ruipfcosta/SwiftyWalkthrough . However, they want me code a lib which they can pass the views and my lib will do everything, step by step. (cwl). I think I should write a letter of resignation.