# Discussion Swift - Popup ToolTip

Tags: ios, swift, popup, tooltip, popover

I have to customise a lib/module, which can show a tooltip look like this image:

[image]

But I have no idea about this. Can anyone give me some advices or ideas? All helps are appreciate.

**Update:**

I found a lib which is similar to what I am looking for and trying to use: https://github.com/ruipfcosta/SwiftyWalkthrough

Please, leave a comment or an answer if you can help.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? If you are looking for a button with image and text check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954880/left-align-image-and-center-text-on-uibutton

Comment: I have a screen with many buttons. And I want to show introduction about the buttons' function. When I click the button, a tutorial popup appear. However, the item I clicked should be highlight (see the image). The rest of view will have black background color. (Don't mind the curve image)

Comment: I dont know any simple way of doing something like this. But one way is every time you tap on a button get the CGRect of the button on screen and add full screen partially transparent view on top of current view with fully transparent box (hole) above tapped button. Then add text accordingly on that view. check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711248/cut-transparent-hole-in-uiview

Comment: I found a lib look like what I need. I try to understand their code: https://github.com/ruipfcosta/SwiftyWalkthrough